# How to add conditional tooltip in bootstrap 3,it should be visible only when ellipses(large text) is there

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, tooltip, conditional-statements

How to add conditional tool tip in bootstrap 3,it should be visible only when ellipses(large text) is there.

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: <a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title=This is a large text">This is a large text</a>

Comment: <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip(); 
});
</script>

Comment: now as the tittle value will be large or small(dynamic values are coming),i want to show tool tip when there is larger text.

Comment: is there is way to make conditions in title attribute

Answer (score 0):

you can add the title tag with JavaScript within your condition (if, else, or whatever)

```
document.getElementById('myID').setAttribute('title', 'your tooltiptext');
```

dont Forget to set the id of your a-tag..